# Changing default culture for windows service running as LocalSystem

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, windows-services, windows-server-2008

Our admins unexpectedly migrated a server where my .NET windows service runs (to Windows 2008 ... because of some old apps). It is running under LocalSystem account. The target framework is .NET framework 4 Client Profile.

In my service the method `DateTime.Parse` now throws invalid format exception.

When I add to `OnStart`

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("cs-CZ", false);
```

it gets better, but still in some methods it fails, probably running in different therads.

How to configure the server or change the program to make all threads be created with proper culture?

Comment: on which framework version? maybe [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.defaultthreadcurrentculture(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @dlatikay  .NET framework 4 Client Profile

Comment: So do I need to rebuild for 4.5?

Comment: No, you'll [really like 4.6](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5145097/17034).

Comment: both versions will install on a Windows Server 2008 SP2, so this, or find all lines that spawn threads, or find all occurrences of `DateTime.Parse` and `DateTime.ToString` and the like, and use their `provider` argument to inject the culture.

Comment: @dlatikay I have built it in 4.52 and used DefaultCulture, could you post an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting with Microsoft.NET Framework 4.5 and higher, you can use

```
var culture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("cs-CZ");
CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = culture;
```

This is [documented here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.defaultthreadcurrentculture(v=vs.110).aspx), with the caveat that it might not work for subsequently created threads. A profound solution is included with Microsoft.NET Framework 4.6, [read more on it here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5145097/1132334).