# DateTime.Now giving different formats in the same machine

Tags: c#

I have a windows service application in which I am getting the current date and time using DateTime.Now.ToString(), which returns '**04-05-2018 05:50:12**'.

But I tried the same in a sample console application, but it returns the date in a different format as '**5/4/2018 5:51:32 AM**'

Both these machines are being executed in the same machine. Can some one let me know why is there a date format difference in these applications?

Comment: I imagine that the service account has different culture settings to you.

Comment: John, How can I check this ?

Comment: I'm not sure, but you can change it at the service start like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44239161/changing-default-culture-for-windows-service-running-as-localsystem).

Comment: John, I am building the application in .Net 4

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentculture(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: If you want a specific format then specifiy a format string e.g. `DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss")`

Comment: Just out of curiosity, is there are a reason why you're not formatting the date to the format you desire? i.e. `DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:tt")`?

Answer (score 2):

The DateTime.ToString() formats the DateTime according to [current culture](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentculture(v=vs.110).aspx). As Written in the [Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tostring(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Converts the value of the current DateTime object to its equivalent
>   string representation using the formatting conventions of the current
>   culture.(Overrides ValueType.ToString().)

If you want the same string you should instead use the [DateTime.ToString(string)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw(v=vs.110).aspx) overload and provide the exact format which you want.

> The ToString(String) method returns the string representation of a
>   date and time value in a specific format that uses the formatting
>   conventions of the current culture; for more information, see
>   CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.
>
> The format parameter should contain either a single format specifier
>   character (see Standard Date and Time Format Strings) or a custom
>   format pattern (see Custom Date and Time Format Strings) that defines
>   the format of the returned string. If format is null or an empty
>   string, the general format specifier, 'G', is used.
>
> Some uses of this method include:
>
> Getting a string that displays the date and time in the current
>   culture’s short date and time format. To do this, you use the “G”
>   format specifier.
>
> Getting a string that contains only the month and year. To do this,
>   you use the “MM/yyyy” format string. The format string uses the
>   current culture’s date separator.
>
> Getting a string that contains the date and time in a specific format.
>   For example, the “MM/dd/yyyyHH:mm” format string displays the date and
>   time string in a fixed format such as “19//03//2013 18:06". The format
>   string uses “/” as a fixed date separator regardless of
>   culture-specific settings.
>
> Getting a date in a condensed format that could be used for
>   serializing a date string. For example, the "yyyyMMdd" format string
>   displays a four-digit year followed by a two-digit month and a
>   two-digit day with no date separator.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, though.  The question is, why is it different between a Windows Service application and a Console application _on the same machine_?  In theory, the current culture should be same for both applications.